# Connect headset via micro USB input

Tags: usb, headphones

Is there any possible way to run a headset that have micro USB output to connect to a Android LG phone by micro USB input?

Comment: We'll need more information to give you a complete answer. Which phone do you have? Which headset? What do you want to do with it?

In the meantime, Android Lollipop [apparently has native support for USB audio](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/07/04/android-l-feature-spotlight-android-now-natively-supports-usb-audio-out/). So if your phone runs Lollipop, you may be in luck!